# How to get object from which function was called?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6

Here is one of mine difficult to answer questions.
I am trying to create a function which can detect from what object and what property it was called. The function has to work for any method or any property of any class. Here is what is my goal:

```
Object.prototype.WHO_AM_I = function WHO_AM_I()
{
    print("FUNCTION CALLED FROM: ? ITEM IN ?? CLASS.");
}

class CLASS
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.PROPERTY = "";
    }
    METHOD()
    {
        return;
    }
}

let OBJECT = new CLASS()
OBJECT.PROPERTY.WHO_AM_I();
OBJECT.METHOD.WHO_AM_I();
```

What I want this code to output is:

```
FUNCTION CALLED FROM PROPERTY ITEM IN CLASS CLASS.
FUNCTION CALLED FROM METHOD ITEM IN CLASS CLASS.
```

So, my goal is to get the name of the method or property upon which function `WHO_AM_I` was called and name of the class in which this item is defined.

example 2:

```
"TEST".substring.WHO_AM_I();
[].length.WHO_AM_I();
```

Should output:

```
FUNCTION CALLED FROM: substring ITEM IN String CLASS.
FUNCTION CALLED FROM length ITEM IN Array CLASS.
```

I hope you get the picture. So what I do is to inject the `WHO_AM_I` method in every object created in the whole javascript, and want to be able to call this method upon any method or any property of any class in the whole javascript regardless whether it is my own class or java script's built-in class.

I can use `this` inside `WHO_AM_I` method. This will get me a reference to either property or method upon which `WHO_AM_I` method was called. But the real problem is how do I  get the class in which this method or property is defined? I can not figure that out. `super` does not help, since it points to the parent object of the item, not to object where an item is defined. Plus, I can not get the name of the item unless the item is method in which case I can use `this.name` to get the name of the method. And there is where I have stuck. I am able to solve this problem for first? mark in `WHO_AM_I` method if I put `this.name`, but it works only in case I call `WHO_AM_I` method upon another method, but not upon the property of a class. But I can not solve this problem for a second ?? question mark at all.

So my question is:
Is it possible in javascript to find out in which class method is defined?
And if it is, what should I put in place of `?` and `??` in my `WHO_AM_I` method I injected into java scripts Object class to produce the output I want?

Comment: This is not possible by default, functions and objects are not aware of their location. Although, You might be able to use reflection or proxies to set up parent aware objects explicitly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible - you'd need to use (for example) a Proxy object, unless you choose to use the non-standard [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) property (check the compatibility table).

Comment: I don't see how even `.caller` might help here - OP is never calling the target function

Comment: Ok, so it is not possible unless I create one proxy for each item upon which I want to be able to use that method, what is ridiculous. Yes, as @bergi said, I would have to actually call that function to be able to access ```caller``` property, and I want to do it upon function object without executing that function. Plus this would not work for properties, just for functions, and I am trying to make universal method which can work on both properties (variables) and methods (functions)...

Comment: ...Plus it is not supported in my environment anyway (which is not defined in compatibility table - i use Mongo as my javascript interpreter). In any case, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.
Even if you can get the context (`this`) of the function, you will not be able to get the context of that context.

I believe you are trying to solve some problem with a wrong approach.
Can you please share what is you initial idea. Why did you decide to get those `?` and `??`?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195037/discussion-on-answer-by-seelts-how-to-get-object-from-which-function-was-called).